# why the laravel app does not read my codes?

Tags: php, laravel, file

i have a form storing data into database ( text and images), it was working fine.
but now, when im trying to upload, it does not read my code from controller.
im changing the code in controller but it read the old codes and return message.
is it about the cache? from where it reads the codes and executing them?

all routes and methods are correct.
actually i have tried `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear` but it does not worked. i dont know from where it finds and reads the codes to execute?
using laravel 5.4

Comment: restart the server too after executing these command

Comment: still the same error :(

Comment: Are you using opcache or similar? You may need to reload the fpm process after each deployment.